# AutoLayout-related crash in iOS 7: "_UIPageViewControllerContentView's implementation of -layoutSubviews needs to call super."

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, autolayout

So I've been wracking my brains for a couple of days now trying to figure out this problem. Context: I have a custom UIPageViewController which I'm adding as a child to another view controller. *This works perfectly fine in iOS 8*, but crashes with the following error in iOS 7.1:

> *** Assertion failure in -[_UIPageViewControllerContentView layoutSublayersOfLayer:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-2935.137/UIView.m:8794
>
> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Auto Layout still required after executing -layoutSubviews. _UIPageViewControllerContentView's implementation of -layoutSubviews needs to call super.'

This is a similar problem to the one posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12610783/auto-layout-still-required-after-executing-layoutsubviews-with-uitableviewcel) and in a few other places, but none of the solutions have worked for me yet (and I have tried *many*).

Now, what is interesting is that if I don't add any subviews or any page view controllers, it runs. But if I write this in viewDidLoad, it's enough to make it crash with the same error as above:

```
UIView *myView = [[UIView alloc] init];
myView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
[self.view addSubview:myView];
[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[myView]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(myView)]];
[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[myView(60)]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(myView)]];
```

Or if I add page view controllers, it crashes with the same error as soon as I navigate to them.

I have tried adding this in my subclassed UIPageViewController as advised [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18429728/autolayout-and-subviews), but it does not help either:

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
}
```

I suspect it is a bug with _UIPageViewControllerContentView's implementation, but I don't know for sure, and have not figured out how to swizzle its layoutSubviews method (like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12941256/1077679)) since it is a private class.

Here is how I add my page view controller to its parent:

```
self.myPageViewController = [[MyPageViewController alloc] initWithObject:object];
[self addChildViewController:self.myPageViewController];

self.myPageViewController.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
[self.containerView addSubview:self.myPageViewController.view];
[self.myPageViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];

NSDictionary *viewsDictionary = @{@"pageView" : self.myPageViewController.view};
[self.containerView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-0-[pageView]-0-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:viewsDictionary]];
[self.containerView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-0-[pageView]-0-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:viewsDictionary]];
```

I would be thrilled if anyone had a solution to this problem. If any other details may help, I'd be happy to supply them here. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I'm having the exact same problem as you and just found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21818091/how-do-i-position-a-subview-in-uipageviewcontroller-using-auto-layout). Basically Auto Layout is not supported in `UIPageViewController` on iOS 7, so replace it with a custom container controller.

Comment: Yeah, I ended up just writing my own subclass of UIScrollViewController, which I sort of wanted or needed to do anyway. Wish I'd've done that from the get-go ...